# CoreData insertNewObjectForEntityForName and executeFetchRequest return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'll try to expose my problem, because is a bit complex.
I use **Core Data** and I have a problem with the data stored. 
When I use this code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ItemMessage"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (error == nil) {
    for (int i = 0; i<results.count; i++) {
        NSLog(@"results %@",[results objectAtIndex:i]);
        ItemMessage *itemMessage = [results objectAtIndex:i];
        [values addObject:itemMessage];
    }
```

ecc. the problem is that the value printed by NSLog is correct (the "results" contains something) but the itemMessage contains always 0 key/value pairs (it seems empty). 
To understand what is the problem I went back and saw that in `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` I have also this problem, this is the code that I used when I save the messages data in **Core Data**:

```
for (id key in objectMessage) {
    ItemMessage *itemmessage = [[ItemMessage alloc] init];
    itemmessage.itemMessageId = [key objectForKey:@"itemMessageId"];
    itemmessage.message = [key objectForKey:@"message"];
    itemmessage.sender = [key objectForKey:@"sender"];
    itemmessage.users = [key objectForKey:@"users"];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newMessage;
    newMessage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ItemMessage" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newMessage setValue: itemmessage.itemMessageId forKey:@"itemMessageId"];
    [newMessage setValue: itemmessage.message forKey:@"message"];
    [newMessage setValue: itemmessage.sender forKey:@"sender"];
    [newMessage setValue: itemmessage.users forKey:@"users"];
    [context save:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Coredata error");
    }
```

The problem is that `newMessage` after the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` and the `setValue` contains also 0 key/value pairs.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to insert the new managed objects correctly into the context.
It should be:

```
for (id key in objectMessage) {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    ItemMessage *itemmessage = (ItemMessage*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ItemMessage" 
                                                                           inManagedObjectContext:context];
    itemmessage.itemMessageId = [key objectForKey:@"itemMessageId"];
    itemmessage.message = [key objectForKey:@"message"];
    itemmessage.sender = [key objectForKey:@"sender"];
    itemmessage.users = [key objectForKey:@"users"];
}
//save your inserts
```

To create a class file for your managed objects you could:

Go to your model file (xcdatamodeld) ->
select an entity ->
from the menu select:
Editor-> Create NSManagedObjectSubclass -> select the entities your like class files for.

Now you will have managed objects you could access with ease (NSManagedObject subclass) and benefit from CoreData features.

Comment: This is not my problem, simply I've not included part of code. Now I have edited the post and I have written all the code!

Comment: What is `ItemMessage` (is it a managed object)? why do you need it? how is your managed object defined?

Comment: ItemMessage is a Coredata entity, is defined in the xcdatamodeld and also is a model with the same name (a NSObject class)

Comment: a managed object (NSManagedObject subclass) should not be "alloc init" manually, but introduced to the context using the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` method, so your loop code is doing something its not suppose to do. look at my answer again.

Comment: Ok, you're right, but the ItemMessage *itemmessage = [[ItemMessage alloc] init] is not a NSManagedObject but a NSObject. Probably my question is: can I use a NSObject model with the same name of a NSManagedObject coredata entity?

Comment: This will defeat the whole purpose of using CoreData. look at my edit

Answer (score 2):

When you insert to manage object contest you have to call save: method, also the saving method should looks something like that:

```
newMessage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ItemMessage" inManagedObjectContext:context];
//  2
  newMessage.property1 = self.firstNameTextfield.text;
  newMessage.property2 = self.lastNameTextfield.text;

if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you but I've not included part of code. Of course I set the newMessages values with (for instance) [newMessage setValue: itemmessage.message forKey:@"message"]; and at the end I save with [context save:&error];
And the save don't give any error.

Comment: Can you show that code where you set up the properties and save it.